# Update GEOS to 3.4

Tags: r, geos

I want to use the rgeos function gDelaunayTriangulation (which requires GEOS 3.4) on my Mac, but when I load rgeos it says:

```
> library(rgeos)
rgeos version: 0.3-2, (SVN revision 413M)
GEOS runtime version: 3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4
```

I have installed and uninstalled both rgeos and GEOS (GEOS framework v3.4.2-2 from www.kyngchaos.com) a number of times and in different orders, but no matter how I try do I get rgeos to say the runtime is anything else than 3.3.3.

What should I do to get GEOS 3.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an older version of GEOS installed.

Open the Terminal.app and type

```
geos-config --version
```

your result should be 3.3.3

Now, to find the file being used

```
which geos-config
?????
```

If you install the GEOS version of Kyngchaos, the result should be:

```
 geos-config --version
 3.4.2
 which geos-config 
 /Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin/geos-config
```

If not, you must adjust the path of GEOS in you bash_profile file (.bash_profile) or compile the rgeos package from source with the option

```
 --with-geos=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/unix.
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. When I run “geos-config --version” then I get:
-bash: geos-config: command not found
But after I run export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin:$PATH GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH='/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/GEOS'
then I get
3.4.2
I then uninstalled and reinstalled rgeos, but still get 3.3.3. Could I have another installation of GEOS I must delete?

Comment: yes, but you need to find it...

Comment: or put `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/bin:$PATH` in your .bash_profile file

Comment: Ok. I added the path, but in R I still get 3.3.3. I suspect it is hardcoded in the Mac OS binary for rgeos (the package that should use GEOS).

Comment: Now got it. I needed to reinstall rgeos from source. First I downloaded the source from CRAN and then (after installing and pathing according to gene) I ran:

sudo R CMD INSTALL rgeos_0.3-2.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-geos-config=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/unix/bin/geos-config'